# Safest / most profittable platform/exchange to sell XMR for BTC (no KYC)

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, exchange

What is there, what would you recommend? I'm only aware of localmonero. A search lead me to decentralized exchange simpleswap - which turns out is not trustworthy (you can find a reddit post about it).

I don't want/can't verify my identity, so centralized exchanges (Binance, FTX etc) are a no-go.

And BTC is one option for exchange, but actually, I'd prefer ETH.

Comment: Coin to coin should be easy with no KYC.  (the fiat on/off ramps are the bottleneck). Tradeogre, plus the Cake and monerjo wallets support swaps.  There is also the atomic swaps, but it is quite new.  Been live for a month or 3.

Comment: @Dave Tradeogre seems to provide only BTC-XMR for sale, I need XMR-BTC/ETH. Monerjo is a typo (doesn't find anything)? Whats Cake, how to search for it?

Comment: I've never been good at spelling monerujo. But that and Cake are mobile wallets on both iOS and Andriod with good reputations.  Do check out www.monero.how It is a good starting point.  To ETH, I'm at a loss, never played with ETH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most top centralized exchanges started to require mandatory KYC, I've turned to localmonero. Successfully sold my XMR for ETH (however I had to cover mining fee which was something like 11$).

Answer (score 1):

Try Bisq, a decentralised, P2P, no KYC, trading application.

You need to already have some BTC to fund security deposits for trade, and to pay transaction fees (much lower if you buy some of the app's native 'BSQ' token for this).

See https://bisq.network/

Also, there is a XMR-BTC atomic swap protocol. The software is still young though. There is a 'asb' binary to make offers to sell XMR for BTC. See: https://github.com/comit-network/xmr-btc-swap

Answer (score 1):

Kucoin has been great to me. I havent used localmonero since I found Kucoin. No kyc, no problems so far, and more options than anyone needs including xmr btc/eth

Comment: Interesting. Seems like Kucoin is based in Singapore and not licensed in US - which makes it much easier to understand why KYC wouldn't be mandatory. Do you have experience in depositing/withdrawing fiat without KYC on this platform?

Answer (score 0):

Stealthex is alright for XMR swaps
this one https://stealthex.io/